# invalidate just one view

Tags: android, view, invalidation

I'm developing an android platform game just for fun.
I have two views overlapping, and when I call invalidate in one of them the other gets redrawn too.
I don't need to redraw the second view, I just need to apply a translation to it, but without redrawing. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you show us What you did so far ?

Comment: for the moment just two custom views extending AppCompatImageView. And when i call invalidate in one of them, the other gets redrawn too. The relevant code is just what I explain. Both views are childs of a RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

if `view1` is overlapping with `view2` when you call `view1.invalidate();` it will re-draw every `View` that is overlapping with it .. so it will call `view2.onDraw();` and since you are using `RelativeLayout` `view1` and `view2` maybe overlapped each other .

generally There is no way for `View` to draw "just itself", since it depends on it's parent (which provides it's clipped and translated `Canvas` via `dispatchDraw` method). Invalidation requires whole view tree to be invalidated .

Comment: I can't believe there is no way to achieve so simple thing in Android... There is no way to have them views in different view trees?